# Using MySQL functions in codeigniter active record method

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am stuck with this query , please tell me how to convert this query into codeigniter active record method

```
select * from view_log where user_id=XXXX and date(time) = curdate();
```

where time is a time stamp , so I want to extract date out of it and compare it with today's date. I have tried to use `set` but its not working, even passing it as a `string` is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('view_log');
  $this->db->where('user_id=XXXX and date(time) = curdate()');
  $result=$this->db->get();
```

or the simplest way

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('view_log');
  $this->db->where('user_id','XXX');
  $this->db->where('DATE(time)', 'CURDATE()', FALSE);
  $result=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?? if yes then please let me know the error that you are getting

Comment: $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); 
$this->db->where("DATE(time)",'CURDATE()',false); This worked for me !
Thank bipen for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I think date is a field in our table

if date is a field in you table try this way

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('view_log');
$this->db->where('user_id','XXX');
$this->db->where('date', 'CURDATE()', FALSE);
$result=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);  $this->db->where("DATE(time)",'CURDATE()',false); This worked for me ! Thank mehdi for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or simplely, you can use this code `$query = $this->db->query($sql);` But before using any mysql query in controller, you should try to run it in phpmyadmin. I think you will know extractly your query is right or wrong ...